# The app doesn't get the localization change effect on nougat api 7 ++

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

I have a custom adapter for my `spinner`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) {

      .............

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.add(context.getResources().getString(R.string.value1));
    adapter.add(context.getResources().getString(R.string.value2));
    adapter.add(context.getResources().getString(R.string.hint));
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Every thing work as expect but list adapter, when i change the application language every thing got the language change effect but the list adapter don't.

I have the resource for both language.

I'm changing language via this method:

```
public  void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

}
```

After i test the case on lower device like lolipop it's worked as well, the current issue with android oreo 8.0.

Since `conf.locale = myLocale;` was deprecated in API level 24.

So i didn't use  `conf.locale = myLocale;`directly. Use `getLocales()` and `setLocales(LocaleList)`. If only the primary locale is needed, `getLocales().get(0)` is now the preferred accessor.

Also `updateConfiguration` was deprecated in API level 25, I used [`createConfigurationContext (Configuration overrideConfiguration)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createConfigurationContext(android.content.res.Configuration)) instead.

But it didn't work, Is i missing something?

Comment: What if you replace it with a new spinner after changing the language? Does it work then?

Comment: "when i change the application language" -- are you changing this for the entire device via Settings, or are you doing something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare updated the question, i'm changing it by application it self.

Comment: @JohnPerry you mean a spinner for each language? if then, of course no.

Comment: @Ibrahim I mean manually create a new spinner & add it to the layout. NOT on a per-language basis; the language ought to be taken care of by the system. The point is to see if the system will create a spinner w/the correct translations when you add a new layout.

Comment: @JohnPerry well i tested it on lolipop device and it's worked, the above issue happened with android oreo version.

Comment: That's one reason I suggest you try it manually. It can help see if the bug is in the system (unlikely) or with an assumption in your code.

Comment: @JohnPerry I assumed once my code worked with whole application but this adapter will explain that, btw what may cause this issue?

Comment: @Ibrahim Well, an oversight on the Android devs' part could explain it: i.e., they didn't traverse all the linked lists they had to traverse after a language change. That's the easy explanation but it's also probably wrong (it's TOO easy), so I don't think that's the case. But creating a new Spinner after the language change & adding it to the layout & seeing if it takes the translated strings would verify whether that's the problem, or (if it doesn't come up with the translations) it's something else.

Comment: @Ibrahim to be clear: I'm not saying this should be your permanent solution. It's just a suggestion to test & see what happens.

Comment: @CommonsWare you have any suggestion?

Comment: No, as I have never tried dynamically changing the locale. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue fixed after passing the Activity `context` instead of `applicationContext` to the `spinnerAdapter`.

Simply I changed `spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext());` to
`spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(MainActivity.this);`

[A REF](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68092459).