# AlertDialog in Android 8.0 Oreo localization issue

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My application supports two languages "English" and "Spanish", while in case of Android 8.0 Oreo text on alert dialogue box remains in English, when selected language is 'Spanish'?

```
AlertDialog dialog = 
      new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity,R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setMessage(
      mActivity.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.log_off_dialog_message)).setNegativeButton(
      mActivity.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.cancel_button), null).setPositiveButton(
      mActivity.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.logout_dialouge_text)
      ,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
           CustomProgressDialog.showProgressDialog(finalLogoutActivity);
           logoutAPI(finalLogoutActivity, view);

        }
     }).show();
```

Comment: Do you have  Spanish translation for that String inside res/values-es/strings.xml?

Comment: @FatihOzcan Yes, and it works for other Android versions.

Comment: @Ibrahim It works in Instagram, So there must be some way to do this.

Comment: Well, what make you sure that instagram use a default AlertDialog?, i think if you customize your alert it will work.

Comment: @Ibrahim yes, that customize AlertDialog will work.. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spinner adapter values doesn't change language on android 7.0 ++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531579/spinner-adapter-values-doesnt-change-language-on-android-7-0)

Comment: This issue because of you are using two different context here and It's fixed in my question.